# Mysql TIMESTAMP: how to validate string in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

In database there is a column in TIMESTAMP type. From console user can enter date in one of these format:

```
TIMESTAMP(14)   YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
TIMESTAMP(12)   YYMMDDHHMMSS
TIMESTAMP(10)   YYMMDDHHMM
TIMESTAMP(8)    YYYYMMDD
TIMESTAMP(6)    YYMMDD
TIMESTAMP(4)    YYMM
TIMESTAMP(2)    YY
```

As mysql docs says: all elements can be separate by any punctuation symbol.

Is there is a way to validate, string variable in php code for conformity of mysql TIMESTAMP format?
Example
migration:

```
    $this->createTable('tweet',[
        'id' => Schema::TYPE_PK,
        'text' => Schema::TYPE_STRING.' NOT NULL',
        'date_written' => Schema::TYPE_TIMESTAMP.' NOT NULL',
        'date_imported' => Schema::TYPE_TIMESTAMP.' NOT NULL',
    ],"ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8");
```

Action:

```
 public function actionIndex()
    {
        $stdin = fopen("php://stdin", "r");

        /**
         * @var TweetShow $tweetShow
         */
        $tweetShow = Yii::$app->get('tweetshow');

        $tweetShow->showStatisticInformMessage();

        $dateAndTime = fgets($stdin);
        try {
            strtotime($dateAndTime);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo "\033[01;31mНеверный формат даты!!!\n";
            die();
        }
```

FROM HERE I WANT TO BE SURE that dateAndTime has mysql TIMESTAMP format

```
    /**
     * @var TweetStatistic $tweetStatistic
     */
    $tweetStatistic = Yii::$app->get('tweetstatistic');

    $statistic = $tweetStatistic->getHashtagsStatisticByDate($dateAndTime);

    $tweetShow->statisticByHashtags($statistic, $dateAndTime);
}
```

strtotime bad solution. user can enter any string which can be parse in unix time.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're after, could you add some examples to your question?

Comment: Ok there is some code from my issue

Comment: I think `strtotime` should work for you. If you give it an invalid timestring, it will return false. https://ideone.com/m6POIn Check the return value, and go from there.

Comment: if user enter 03 september 2016.. yes it will be legal value for strtotime(), but  not for mysql TIMESTAMP

Comment: Well, once you know it's a valid strtotime, you can pass that to date to transform it anyway you want to insert it into the DB. Is that a suitable solution?